# Wordpressmenu gone after prefix change

Tags: wordpress, menu, prefix

for adding more security to a Wordpress website I changed the database prefix.
Mostly everything is working fine but muy custom navigation menu of the website is gone. Now it shows all the articles of the website in the navigation menu.

When I log into the Admin Panel, the "menu configuration site" is not working properly.
There is no custom menu I created. If I try to create a new navigation menu I get a message saying that a new navigation menu was created. But it´s not there and I can not press on the checkbox for adding a post to the menu.

At the moment I am testing it on a local server (Xampp on my computer) with Wordpress 3.5
Before changing the db prefix it was working.

Things I changed in the db:
I renamed every "wp"

```
wp_commentmeta
wp_comments
wp_links
wp_options
wp_postmeta
wp_posts
wp_terms
wp_term_relationships
wp_term_taxonomy
wp_usermeta
wp_users

wp_user_roles
```

And everything inside "wp_usermeta"  that started with "wp"

Does anybody has any idea?

Regards,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to set your menu as primary?

---

I suggest to read the next article about how to change your wp db prefix: http://digwp.com/2010/10/change-database-prefix/

Pay attention for the "*Changing default table prefix after installing WordPress*" section expecially.

Comment: I can´t change anything in the menupage. So at the moment I can´t create a menu, add a post to a menu or set a menu as primary.
It´s like somewhere a "wp_" was hardcoded but I can´t find anything.

Comment: updated my answer based on your further details. please check that articole and follow instructions. let me know then :)

Comment: Hi Gravuj,
thanks for your answer. I checkt everything from the article and it´s just what I did. 

I think I will try the first part form the article (rename the database before installing wordpress). 
Maybe it helps.  I try and let you know.

Comment: I now installed Wordpress again, but before I created a new database and I changed the db prefix in wp-config.php   After that everything is working fine.

I will do it like that when I upload the new website so I don´t have to solve the probleme once Wordpress is installed.

Thank you Gravuj for this useful link.

Comment: Welcome. I thought you have already pretty much content. It's okay changing prefix before wp install. It can be changed from the install page also, not necesary to do changes in wp-config.php Anyway, prefix can be changed also after wp installation, but allways pay high attention on the queries used in your theme files. If you follow best practices, the ones reccomended on wp codex site, or sites like smashingmagazine.com or wp.tutsplus.com, then everything should work like a charm. If not, you can still ask here :)

Comment: I will substitute a html coded website. So I have to create a new database anyway.